# Como hacer un load para un include (Php y Jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

uso un *include* el cual hace muchos *foreach* y eso hace que la página tarde demasiado en carga. Me gustaría que la página cargara rápido haciendo que el *include* carge despues de la página.

Aquí un ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que de la primera imagen pase a la segunda
Aquí esta el código PHP

```
<?php include 'season_episode.php'; ?>
```

Sé que no soy la mejor persona expresandose pero lo que estoy intentando hacer es algo parecido como los comentarios de youtube.com, aparece un loader de cargando comentarios y luego aparecen.
Si no entiende Házmelo saber y edito el post

Comment: Hola Esael, creo que deberias de particionar o separar la logica.
Primero seria cargar la pagina PHP y luego via AJAX asincronico traer mas información utilizando el loader como muestras en las fotos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar jquery para hacer una carga simple por ajax.
Debes elegir o crear un div donde se cargará el contenido.
Pongamos por ejemplo que lo cargas en un div con id season

En vez de hacer esto:

```
<div id='season'>
<?php include 'season_episode.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Habria que cambiarlo por este código jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//Esperas a que se cargue la web
$(document).ready(function(){
//Cargas el php en el div
$('#season').load('season_episode.php');
});
</script>
<div id='season'></div>
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.